# Select elements of list based on number of characters

Tags: python, arrays, math, integer, boolean

Print the elements whose array length is greater than or equal to 4, such as

```
things = ['jump','hop','skip','tip',leap']
```

Comment: iterate over the list (for example with `for value in things:`) and call `len()`

Comment: `[e for e in things if len(e)>=4]`

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to come up with the answer for this yourself.
Some hints are :

1. Use a 'for' loop to iterate through each element of the list [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)
   Example:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

for x in fruits:
 print(x)
```

2. Within the loop, use len() to check the length of each element of the list.
   Example:

```
 if len(element1) >=4: 
    do something
```

Full code as below

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

for x in fruits:
 if len(x) >=4: 
   print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the element lenght is greater than four then you can add them into the desired list

```
new_elements =[element for element in things if len(element)>=4]
print(new_elements)
```

[image]